# How to create an overlay in advanced grid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I'd like to know how to create an "overlay" in Flex's Advanced Grid? See the sample here

http://tinypic.com/r/4ieccm/4

Comment: Isn't that selected item's background color?

Comment: Not really - i.e. if you notice on the picture that the height is little bit bigger than the height of the row.

Comment: looks very nice from the snapshot was taken ?

Comment: snapshot is taken from Mint.com web site.  They have awesome UI.  They just acquired by Quick Books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a datagrid you can override the DrawRowBackground method of the datagrid to do custom backgrounds. I assume there would be something similar to that for the advanceddatagrid.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#drawRowBackground%28%29